# Transparent drag icon is flickering

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pygtk

I'm setting a transparent PNG as a drag icon:

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file('image.png')
ev_box.drag_source_set_icon_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

As soon as I begin a DND operation the transparent parts of the image start flickering.
This happens only on a Linux test system (CentOS). On Windows everything is fine.

Is there a fix or a better workaround than not using a transparent image?

Comment: just out of curiosity, is it the full transparent area that flickers or just the border? Reason I ask is that I have some odd artifacts at the border in my app when a specific image is first loaded, but that disappear after I've hidden and then showed it again... btw, you could try to hide/show it (though it would be odd if it worked)

Comment: What about the graphics hardware and drivers on the two systems? Is hardware acceleration turned on in X?

Comment: @deinonychusaur it is the full transparent area.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy The development system is Win7 with NVIDIA Quadro 4000M. The linux test system is running in a VM (Cent OS, no hardware acceleratinon). But I already tried it on the target system (custom industrial real time linux) and got the same problem. On this system I cannot mess with X config or drivers, I need a software solution...

Comment: OK, but it would still be good to know how X is configured, even if you can't change it. Regardless of whether you need a software solution, it could be a hardware/driver problem.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy As I have the exact same problem on a VM running on a Windows host, I don't think it is driver/hardware related. Anyway, I don't have access to the linux filesystem and cannot read the configuration. On the VM, the xorg.conf is automatically generated from VirtualBox. It contains nothing related to hardware acceleration, just the default stuff (monitor, device, screen).

Comment: Looks like a double buffer issue. I think the flicker is actually the remains of the previous colored part drawn on that point on screen before you moved.
Is your background of solid color? And do you know that color at runtime? If so, try drawing that color on the position your icon was before you moved it.
I don't know about gtk but it worked for me on an application I implemented using a graphics library without double buffering.

Comment: @KuramaYoko This is my guess, too. But sadly I don't have a solid background color. And the icon is flickering everywhere, not only at the start position.

Comment: I was looking at Gtk.Gdk documentation and look what I found on method Pixbuf.render_to_drawable_alpha:
"On older X servers, rendering pixbufs with an alpha channel involves round trips to the X server, and may be somewhat slow"
So maybe, only with the X server updated this is going to work...

Comment: @KuramaYoko No chance to do this, but thanks for the update.